# Reinvest 401K Gains for Compounding Growth

Tags: 401k, compound-interest

I'm a bit confused about compounding growth on my 401K.

Let's say I have $100 and it's up 10% in Year 1 for a total of $110. Now, should I sell this at the end of the year to lock in gains and reinvest $110 to take advantage of compounding growth on $110 or would my 401K do that automatically?

Answer (score 2):

All right, I will try to take this nice and slow. This is going to be a little long; try to bear with me.

Suppose you contribute $100 to your newly opened 401(k). You now have $100 in cash and $0 in mutual funds in your 401(k) (and $100 less than you used to somewhere else).

At some later date, you use that money within the 401(k) to buy a single share of the Acme World All-Market Index Fund which happens to trade at exactly $100 per share on the day your purchase goes through. As a result, you have $0 in cash and exactly one share of that fund (corresponding to $100) within your 401(k).

Some time later, the price of the fund is up 10%, so your share is now worth $110. Since you haven't contributed anything more to your 401(k) for whatever reason, your cash holding is still $0. Because your holding is really denominated in shares of this mutual fund, of which you still have exactly one, the cash equivalent of your holding is now $110.

Now, you can basically do one of two things:

- Sell the share of the mutual fund, resulting in $110 in cash and $0 equivalent in mutual funds within your 401(k), possibly using the cash to buy some other investment or withdrawing it
- Keep the share of the mutual fund, resulting in $0 in cash and $110 equivalent in mutual funds within your 401(k)

By selling the share, you protect against it falling in price, thus in a sense "locking in" your gain. **But where do you put the money instead?** You obviously can't put the money in anything else that might fall in price; doing so would mean that you could lose a portion of your gains. *The only way to truly "lock in" a gain is to remove the money from your investment portfolio altogether.* Roughly speaking, that means withdrawing the money and spending it. (And then you have to consider if the value of what you spent the money on can fluctuate, and as a consequence, fall. What's the value of that three weeks old jug of milk in the back of your refrigerator?)

**The beauty of compounding is that it doesn't care when you bought an investment.**

Let's say that you kept the original fund, which was at $110. Now, since that day, it is up another 5%. Since we are looking at the change of price of the fund over some period of time, that's 5% of $110, not 5% of the $100 you bought at (which was an arbitrary point, anyway). 5% of $110 is $5.50, which means that **the value of your holding is now at $115.50 from a gain first of 10% followed by another 5%.**

If at the same day when the original fund was at $110 you buy another $100 worth of it, the additional 5% gain is realized on the sum of the two at the time of the purchase, or $210. Thus after the additional 5% gain, you would have not $210 (($100 + $100) + 5%), nor $205 (($100 + 5%) + $100), but $220.50 (($110 + $100) + 5%).

**See how you don't need to do anything in particular to realize the beauty of compounding growth?**

**There is one exception to the above.** *Some investments pay out dividends, interest or equivalent in cash equivalents.* (Basically, deposit money into an account of yours somewhere; in the case of retirement plans, usually within the same container where you are holding the investment. These dividends are generally not counted against your contribution limits, but check the relevant legal texts if you want to be absolutely certain.) This is somewhat uncommon in mutual funds, but very common in other investments such as stocks or bonds that you purchase directly (*which you really should not do* if you are just starting out and/or feel the need to ask this type of question). In that case, you need to place a purchase order yourself for whatever you want to invest the dividend in. If you don't, then the extra money of the dividend will not be growing along with your original investment.

Comment: You might want to add to that last section that many investments offer the option of automatically re-investing dividends back into the same holding automatically. If this option is available OP literally needs to do nothing.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is super helpful to understand. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to move money between your investments within the plan, rebalancing money to maintain your diversification. You don't have to deal with the details if selling and buying, just tell them how much to move where.

Many plans offer investments that automatically rebalance for you such as Target Date accounts. You may be able to select one of those and just ignore the 401k until retirement, or at most rebalance even less often. Look at what's offered, look at what it costs as fees, run the numbers and decide whether you can do better.